# Different argument types

Tags: java, arguments

I have a question on design implementation.
So, there are two ways to run the program.

1. pass input , output directory thru command line
2. or read from config file (in this case I pass the argument of config file thru command line)
3. If no arguments is passed throw error

As of now, I have been working with args[0], args[1]...

Is there a way (I am sure there is), so that I can pass flag (like --input --output etc) as arguments in java.

Any suggestions on design implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this apache library focused on your requirement:

http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html

Thus, you will be able to avoid using poor `args` table.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another (simple) alternative

http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/